# Spring MVC Form Object Dont Initialize Correct Data

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have developed part of a application with Spring MVC. 
In here i am loading some values from database to this jsp.

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <label class="input-label">Answer</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <form:input class="form-control required" type="text" id="securityQuestionAnswer1" path="userSecurityQuestionList[0].securityQuestionAnswer"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This Jsp have one form and two submit buttons. I have added two different names and call the controller via those names. 
and catch it with

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"next"})

 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"update"})
```

after changing first loaded values in jsp (Security answer) when i submit the form it comes to correct controller. but it dont catch changed data in that text inputs. it catches old data what loaded when jsp loads. I have gone many debug tests. but same result.

my controller method is like this

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"update"})
  public String updateSecurityQuections(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "userForm")ForogtPasswordForm forogtPasswordForm, BindingResult result,
      ModelMap model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws AccountAlreadyRegisteredException,
      AccountNotFoundException {
```

I want to know how to correctly catch(initialize) all the correct input data to this form in controller class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show your methods code.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting method parameters in following order. It worked for me, sounds like yours is similar case.

```
RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"update"})
public String updateSecurityQuections(ModelMap model,@Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "userForm")ForogtPasswordForm forogtPasswordForm, 
   BindingResult result,
   final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws AccountAlreadyRegisteredException,
  AccountNotFoundException {
```

Comment: Nop Once i have changed this to @ModelAttribute(value = "userForm") @Valid ForogtPasswordForm forogtPasswordForm then it worked but after sometime it didn't i dont know why these things happening